# Custom sorting option WooCommerce archive

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a custom sort option on my WooCommerce archive pages for sorting on best sale item.

So all the sale items come first and the highest discount products are in first place.
I found this snippet to add a custom sorting option.

```
/**
 * Add custom sorting options (asc/desc)
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
  $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        $args['order'] = '';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['random_list'] = 'Random';
    return $sortby;
}
```

But how can i modify it so it outputs the way I want to it to be outputted? For both `simple` and `variable` products